# Trim Shape() horizontally with Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

Trim by Swiftui allowed me to make a circle filled with 2 different colors. The problem i'm facing now is i want to trim my circles from horizontally but the trim only work vertically. I tried using hstack to help this process but it did not work.

Is there any solution to fix this problem?
[image]

```
ZStack {
        //HStack get removed from here
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.5, to: 1)
            .fill(.blue)
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
            .fill(.red)
        Circle()
            .strokeBorder(lineWidth: 24)
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is just to rotate entire view (ZStack in this case)

```
ZStack {
   // ... same code here
}.rotationEffect(.radians(.pi/2))
```

[image: demo]

Comment: i think this should be the answer because shorter

Comment: Or equivalently `.rotationEffect(.degrees(90))`

Comment: Choice of colors in question and answer...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it without rotating. Start with a red circle and cover it with a half blue circle trimmed from `0.25` to `0.75`:

```
ZStack {
    Circle()
        .fill(.red)
    Circle()
        .trim(from: 0.25, to: 0.75)
        .fill(.blue)
    Circle()
        .strokeBorder(lineWidth: 24)
}
```

[image: circle drawn with 2 colors]

Comment: i learn new thing again. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For your information, `HStack` is not the case here.

To achieve your desired design, just rotate your `Circle()` after it is trimmed.

Try this code below:

```
 ZStack {
      Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.5, to: 1)
            .fill(.blue)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
      Circle()
            .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
            .fill(.red)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
      Circle()
            .strokeBorder(lineWidth: 24)
 }
```